# Sum of two (real or not?) gaussian random variables gives a gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, gaussian

I'd like to know if, given two normal random variables $X$ and $Y$, the new random variable $Z=X+Y$ is normal as well. Is it necessary that $X$ and $Y$ are **real** normal random variables or is it sufficient that they are normal random variables?

---

EDIT: $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and $(X, Y)$ is a gaussian random vector.

Comment: What is a non-real normal r.v.? (Sorry, might be a trivial question...)

Comment: Hello @ClementC. I know that there are also complex normal random variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution

Comment: I see. In that case, it seems to be true, since it's equivalent to asking whether the sum of two 2-dimensional normal vectors is still normal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Complex_normal_random_variable

Comment: The sum would be normal if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or if the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is "bivariate normal", but need not be otherwise

Comment: @Henry Urgh, sorry. I thought the question assumed independence, but... it does not.

Comment: @Henry thank you for the clarification. In my case I have $X$ and $Y$ dependent, but $(X, Y)$ gaussian random vector

Comment: If $(X, Y)$ is [bivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) then any linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ (including $X+Y$) is normally distributed

Comment: @Henry if you can suggest me a book or a hangout where I can find the statement that they should be whether real or jointly distributed to be normal would be great

Answer (score 1):

In general, the sum of normal random variables is not normal (unless they are independent). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example) for an example. However, if they are jointly (multivariate) normal, then any linear combination of them will be normal.  In fact, when any linear combination of the components of a random vector is normal, this is one *definition* of being multivariate normal.